# Using Edge Gateway as a "Box" PC

Tags: pc

For a project I needed a box style PC with a small amount of processing power as it's required to run a debian virtual machine, this machine will be processing data from a range of accelerometers connected to the PC via LAN. Our computing team suggested the Dell Edge Gateway 3200 (https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Products_Documents/en/us/dell-edge-gateway-3200-5200-spec-sheet.pdf) as matching the specs I supplied and its seems to ok, but I'm unsure as its branded as a gateway.

It does have Windows 10 and a display output so I'm assuming it'll work ok as a low powered PC but I'd feel stupid if I got it and couldn't use it for the intended purpose as I missed something in the specs (I noticed it does use the low powered atom processor). My question is will a product like this function essentially as a box PC?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is unclear for me what do you search for. Specialized edge computing unit or any small computer (like intel barebone) will be fine? Also to run virtual machine you will need virtualization platform. So what you will run, just Linux or virtualization with Linux as virtual machine>